# why kubernetes create A DNS record for pods?

Tags: kubernetes, dns

why kubernetes create dns record for pod like this: `pod-ip-address.my-namespace.pod.cluster-domain.example`?

because we use dns for finding ip address. but in this format, before using dns we should have ip address of pod. in other words, if I had the Ip address of pod there was no need for dns.

Answer (score 0):

To access without an IP address, you need to create a service. You can specify the pod using the "selector" in service definition. You can connect to the pod using either "servicename.namespace" or "servicename.namespace.svc.cluster.local" without requiring an IP address.

Comment: my question was why k8s includes pod's IP address in it's DNS record as mentioned in k8s [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods)

Comment: Pods communicate over a virtual network. Since multiple pods provide the same service, it's necessary to distinguish between them (pods transition to a running state with a different IP address when they go down due to an error). Kubernetes provides a pod-level solution by adding the IP address as a DNS record, as mentioned in your doc. Kubernetes specifies that a service must be used to access pods that perform the same function. [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/connect-applications-service/)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the @furkan answer, you should never communicate directly with a POD from outside K8s (there are some cases when you need to do it from inside K8s, but in most cases, you need to use Service.

Normal traffic flow is Load Balancer -> Nginx Ingress -> Service -> PODs. If you are operating non-HTTP traffic, you can drop Nginx Ingress.

You can find more details in the official documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/